# Basic rails setup problem - possibly routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, installation, passenger

I'm trying to set up a blank rails app on my VPS - it's at bytemark.co.uk who operate a custom system called symbiosis for hosting sites.

The site in question is at http://svn.chambersjudd.com/

The way bytemark serves sites means the doc root is in the folder public/htdocs.

There is a basic rails app in the public folder, and I have created a symlink betwen htdocs and the rails public folder. The page is loading, but when I click "About your application’s environment"I get "The requested URL /rails/info/properties was not found on this server".

Does anyone have any idea about what could be going on? I'm running passenger if that's of any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your application is running in `production` mode. That link is only available when your application is running in `development`.